# App crashing when Selecting/Scrolling items on Spinner. (LG Mobile) (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iteration already started)

Tags: android, crash, spinner, android-5.0-lollipop

I made on app in which User has to select an integer from the `Spinner`. I am populating the `Spinner` using `Adapter`. The code is like this.

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[500];
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            intArray[i] = i + 1;

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, intArray);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The app is written for `API-21`. It worked perfectly on `Samsung-mobile` but when I tried to run it on `LG-Mobile`, the app is crashing whenever i am scrolling the items in the spinner. The Error is something new as i didn't find similar error. Error goes like this

```
process: com.example.temp.project, PID: 12142
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iteration already started
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver$CopyOnWriteArray.start(ViewTreeObserver.java:987)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:811)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1524)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1654)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1607)
            at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:612)
            at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.access$701(Spinner.java:1069)
            at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup$2.onGlobalLayout(Spinner.java:1178)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:815)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1524)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1654)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1607)
            at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:612)
            at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$ResizePopupRunnable.run(ListPopupWindow.java:1759)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Any hint that how can i solve this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue on a LG G2 with (android 5.0.2), but on my Nexus 5 (android 6.0) and on a LG G4 (android 6.0) the scrolling works fine.

Comment: also no issue on LG G3 (android 5.0.1) and LG Leon (android 5.0.1)

Comment: I solved this issue. Actually, it was layout issue. Spinner needs to be on the top of other background layouts. Previously, `GraphView` charts were front layout but now I put Spinners on the front layout and it's working okay.

Comment: Well, i don't have any specific answer, I just changed my `XML` file structure. Just moved the `Spinner` on top of the `GraphView`. Well it's not because of `Adapter`. Adapters were touched on every device but `app` crashed only in `LG`.

Comment: I posted the `XML` solution.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. It might not be a perfect solution but worked for me. In my original `XML` file, i was using `GraphView` above the `spinner's Layout`, like this

```
<LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/main_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graph_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/SSspinner"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/Avgspinner"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The problem was kind of new as i didn't find any problem like this on net. After reading from different sources, i realized it is layout issue. This is what I did then

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/SSspinner"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/Avgspinner"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


 <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
                android:id="@+id/graph_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862449/app-crashing-when-selecting-scrolling-items-on-spinner-lg-mobile-java-lang-i#comment56259174_33862449):

> solved this issue. Actually, it was layout issue. Spinner needs to be on the top of other background layouts. Previously, GraphView charts were front layout but now I put Spinners on the front layout and it's working okay.

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862449/app-crashing-when-selecting-scrolling-items-on-spinner-lg-mobile-java-lang-i/34335911#comment56304705_33862449):

> Well, I don't have any specific answer, I just changed my XML file structure. Just moved the Spinner on top of the GraphView. Well it's not because of Adapter. Adapters were touched on every device but app crashed only in LG

As suggested here: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Answer (score 0):

Till you / (as well as we) dont have a perfect answer, try enclosing the statements in a try and catch block, so that you may get a clue as to where the iteration (on what index) is failing...

```
  Integer[] intArray = new Integer[500];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        intArray[i] = i + 1;
      ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = null;
      try {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, intArray);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch(Exception e)
    { 
           System.out.println("Iteration is "+i);
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```